# Skype error in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, skype, gnome2

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 version. Recently I am finding this error. When I used to close the Skype client, then it used to go up to the desktop. (The above panel where time and date are generally displayed.) Now, when I am closing, it gets closed and I don't know where it's located. Then, when I try to sign in again, it says another Skype version is running.

Any ideas on how to rectify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might accidentaly have removed the "system tray" from the top panel. Do other applications still show their icons at the top?

Comment: yes, they show. but when closing skype it remains closed. Let me check